# Mi mysql esta usando muchos recursos del server

Tags: mysql, aws, server

Muy buenas, amigos, tengo un mysql que está usando muchos recursos del servidor donde se encuentra instalado, este server se encuentra en aws.
Esto ocasiona que la aplicación que está usando dicha base de datos de mysql funcione muy lenta.

He intentado verificar que proceso dentro de mysql puede estar consumiendo la mayoría de los recursos del Sever, pero hasta ahora no he podido evidenciarlo.

Estoy usando putty para la conexión al server el cual es un ubuntu.

adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solicito ideas de como poder verificar lo antes mencionado. De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Mucha memoria? CPU? Red? Todas las anteriores? Cómo tienes desplegado ese mysql, en un RDS o en un EC2?

Comment: Usa mucha cpu y esta desplegado en un ec2

Answer (score 0):

Pues, si es un MySQL que uno instala a mano en AWS, seguramente pasa que está mal configurado  o la aplicación lo usa de una forma que genera líos con la configuración que tiene. No sabemos si la aplicación tiene un montón de tráfico o no, si lo llama cada 0.0001ms o cada hora, etc.

Algunas cosas a revisar:

- Revisa las sesiones activas. A ver qué usuarios tienen sesiones iniciadas y desde dónde.
- Habilita el [Slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html) pa ver si hay consultas que se demoran un montón y ponen todo en cola.
- Ejecuta `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` en la terminal de MySQL para ver qué procesos están corriendo en la BD y en qué estado están
- Revisa cómo [está configurado](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html) el uso de memoria de la BD. Si le das muy poca, posiblemente tenga que compensar usando más CPU porque tiene que hacer más veces algo (traer fragmentos de datos para armar un resultset).
  Esto último implica revisar varios parámetros de configuración que dependen de si usas InnoDB o MyISAM. Si dejaste parámetros por defecto para todo, es posible que te estés quedando corto (de nuevo, no sabemos nada de la aplicación ni de tu despliegue).